# jQuery TD resize event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, html-table

What do I do if I want to know when a <td>'s size changes?

table code:

```
<style>
    #BA1{
        border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        padding:5px;
    }
    #BA1 th {
        border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
        padding:5px;
        background:#F0F0F0;
    }
    #BA1 td {
        border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
        padding:5px;
    }
</style>
   <table id="BA1">     <caption> </caption>    <thead>     <tr>        <th>Header 1</th>       <th>Header 2</th>       <th>Header 3</th>       <th>Header 4</th>   </tr>   </thead>    <tbody>     <tr>        <td>&nbsp;</td>         <td>&nbsp;</td>         <td>&nbsp;</td>         <td>&nbsp;</td>     </tr>   <tr>        <td>&nbsp;dfdfdfdfdfdf</td>         <td>&nbsp;</td>         <td>&nbsp;</td>         <td>&nbsp;</td>     </tr>   <tr>        <td>&nbsp;</td>         <td>&nbsp;</td>         <td>&nbsp;</td>         <td>&nbsp;</td>     </tr>   <tr>        <td>&nbsp;</td>         <td>&nbsp;</td>         <td>&nbsp;</td>         <td>&nbsp;</td>     </tr>   </tbody> </table>
```

How can i listen this event?

I have tried these methods:

```
var x = 0;
  $("td").resize(function(){ 
   var txt = x += 1;
  });

//planB
$("td").addEventListener("resize", myFunction);

var x = 0;
function myFunction() {
    var txt = x += 1; 
}
```

But this code is not working

How can i fix this?

Comment: Resizing occurs when the user resizes the window.  That is what your listener should assigned to.  In jQuery, http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to accomplish with `var txt = x += 1;` -- you are assigning a value to the variable `txt` but then you never do anything with that value.